# Python- while merging two dataframes to get common value, o/p dataframe is empty , but it has entries present as per dataframe.info()

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df1
    view1              rate1
0   BEDSTE..            1.0
1   Passat: 122 stk.    0.0
2   Billetter..         1.0
3   -De tre f...        1.0
4   -optræden  ...      0.0

len(df1) : 60,000
```

Another dafatframe :
df2

```
    view1
0   kursmål aktien kr
1   sidste sidste åbnings...
2   danske slu...
3   fordel ærgr...
4   llene skodas nye tilbu...

len(df2): 772,000
```

I want to merge both dataframes (keeping common values of view1) and the corresponding scores wrt 'view1'.

I did 
    common = df1.merge(df2,on=['view1'])

Output is

```
    view1   rate1
0           1.0
1           1.0
2           1.0
3           1.0
4           1.0
```

By checking common.info(), I get:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 4576 entries, 0 to 4575
Data columns (total 2 columns):
view1    4576 non-null object
rate1    4576 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 107.2+ KB
```

- I know there are common values, but why does the output looks empty and the second column all rows have vale as '1' only. The code works fine for smaller sample set I tried on.

Comment: In my opinion there is problem some empty duplicated values in column `view1`

Comment: This may be because your df1 is containing Blank value. show me the result of this df1.isnull().sum(axis=0) , df2.isnull().sum(axis=0)

Comment: Yes, there were empty values. Thanks for the help!!